# Windows 10 can’t connect to intranet devices

Tags: windows-10, lan, shared-folders, intranet

I’m trying to connect to my intranet devices but I cannot connect to any of them because Windows says that it cannot find the destination.

I tried with wireless and it worked tried with LAN and it is unreachable.

- Ping in LAN works to intranet devices.
- Network in explorer finds the device.
- I can’t access the web of the device (I’m trying with a Synology NAS and a TP-LINK AP and none of therse work).
- I can access to other computer that has Windows 10
- I tried to reinstall drivers, uninstall antivirus.
- I am directly connected to a router with integrated switch type [Netgear CG3100D](https://www.comhem.se/blob/43612/3/manual-netgear-cg3100-data.pdf) DNS activated , netmask `255.255.255.0`, net `192.168.1.X`
- The first  device is a Synology NAS DS412J and is directly connected to the router. It has a static IP and it has a windows folder. Service and a web front end based in Java.
- The second one is a PLC device—a [TP-LINK Tl-WPA281](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-18_TL-WPA281.html)—and has a web access.
- They work when I use a wireless connection and I can access to them with an old PC with Windows 10 Pro but I can’t access to a direct lan with an Ethernet connection type [Killer e2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2630707/update-killer-e2200-gigabit-ethernet-controller-ndis.html) with dynamic IP, default settings.

That’s why I think I have a problem with the driver or with some    Windows configuration but I don’t know which one.

I tried to direct connect to the PLC (TP-LINK Tl-WPA281) through a cable using a static IP (the PLC has a static IP too) in my laptop but again it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

Installed the latests drivers from  http://www.killernetworking.com/support/driver-downloads 
and now it works fine. 
There was an issue in the driver.
Last time I tried once to install the drivers in windows 10, 10 days ago but it caused a blue screen while rebooting but now  with the last release it works.